# Android Studio empty project errors

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am getting errors on my very first empty project. I've tried everything from reinstalling older version to the new one. I'm new to this and it's already holding me up. I've tried starting empty project but no good.

[error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuUcv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set your target SDK version to 27. Set your compile SDK version to 27. And app compat version from `28.0.0-alpha3` to `27.1.1` .

If you still want to use SDK version 28

Just replace `alpha3` to `alpha1` without changing anything else

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: go to build.gradle(app)